# Mutidex and Kotlin

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, android-multidex

I am working on a project where we use multidex to build our app. I started to see many error like this in our build:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.pcollections.MapEntry
```

Many classes related to kotlin.reflect started be not found in the build. It only happens in APIs 19 and bellow.

Does anyone knows what may be causing this and how to solve this problems?

Comment: Can you show us the code in which you are getting the error?

Comment: Hi Fondesa, I would love to... But this problem is in the whole app, not a particular piece of code. The problem occurs sometimes when I try to run UI tests in the app. If I add classes to the multidex_keep_file I can run UI tests, but I get NoClassDefFoundError with some pcollections class =/

Comment: Do you have `kotlin-reflect` dependency in your project?

Comment: You didn't extend your Application class from `MultiDexApplication`. :|

Comment: Thanks for the help @EpicPandaForce, but I did extend the MultiDexApplication. Everything was working... I commited some changes in the code and then it started to break (changes were not related to kotlin.reflect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [multiDexKeepFile](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/2.2/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType:multiDexKeepFile) api

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            ...
            multiDexEnabled true
            multiDexKeepFile file('multidex_keep_file.txt')
        }
    }
}
```

Where `multidex_keep_file.txt` is file with single class per line which needs to be explicitly added to the main dex

```
 kotlin/reflect/MyClass.class
```

You can also use `multiDexKeepProguard` to keep whole package

```
-keep class kotlin.reflect.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

As specified in https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

If you do `multiDexEnabled true`

then you must also provide a custom application class that `extends MultiDexApplication`

Or calls `MultiDex.install(this)` in `attachBaseContext()` method.

```
public class MyApplication extends SomeOtherApplication {
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(base);
     MultiDex.install(this);
  }
}
```

and

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="com.acme.MyApplication" >
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this was already done in the project